# R ave or apply? adding columns by a function with strata variable, but fast and multiple columns

Tags: r, matrix, apply

In R:

I am not sure what the proper title for this question is, so maybe someone can help me out. It would be greatly appreciated. I'm sorry if this is called something easily searchable.

So I have a ragged array matrix (multiple UPCS)

```
       [upc]    [quantity1]   [quantity2]    [sum1]       [sum2]
[1]  123         11               3              NA         NA   
[2]  123          2               1              NA        ...
[3]  789          5               3              NA 
[4]  456         10               6              NA 
[5]  789          6               2              NA         NA
```

I want the matrix to be summed by UPC, for example:

```
       [upc]    [quantity1]   [quantity2]    [sum1]       [sum2]
[1]  123         11               3              13         4   
[2]  123          2               1              13         4
[3]  789          5               3              11         5
[4]  456         10               6              10         6
[5]  789          6               2              11         5
```

Thank you for your time and help.

The trick is it need to be done in the most efficient way possible, since it will be done many times.

Comment: Where is the `day` column? What are you grouping by?

Comment: Sorry, forget the day, just by upc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are in a `data.frame` the usual way to get the same function applied to the same grouping variables is with the `aggregate` function, but it doesn't behave like `ave` and returns a shorter result. I suspect it's not as fast as using `data.table`, dplyr functions, or Rcpp approaches, either.

```
aggregate( df[ , 2:3], df[1], sum)
```

This would be the way with a data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
setkey(dt, "upc")
# To show you what the inner expression would return
 dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by="upc"]
#-----------    
upc quantity1 quantity2
1: 123        13         4
2: 456        10         6
3: 789        11         5
#-----------    
 dt[ dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by="upc"] ]   # It is a self join operation
   upc quantity1 quantity2 quantity1.1 quantity2.1
1: 123        11         3          13           4
2: 123         2         1          13           4
3: 456        10         6          10           6
4: 789         5         3          11           5
5: 789         6         2          11           5
```

But then to return to the less efficient data.frame methods ....to get that first argument to sit alongside the source columns you would `merge` by upc:

```
> merge(df, aggregate( df[ , 2:3], df[1], sum), by="upc")
  upc quantity1.x quantity2.x quantity1.y quantity2.y
1 123          11           3          13           4
2 123           2           1          13           4
3 456          10           6          10           6
4 789           5           3          11           5
5 789           6           2          11           5
```

Comment: This also works with data.table: `dt[, paste0(names(dt)[-1], "_sum") := lapply(.SD, sum), by = upc]`

Comment: The ability to have a vector of target names is a definite improvement. I didn't realize that `:=` was designed to accept that. Further evidence that I am a data.table beginner.